# my node js server can not get parameters or data from react js client request

Tags: node.js

My server code as following:

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.post('/user', function (req, res) {
   console.log("request body:"+req.body+" params:"+req.params);
})
```

my client code using react js as following:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const post ={
       name:"Tom"
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost:9111/user', { post })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({response:res.data})
      })
}
```

I'm sure the server side did get the request from client, but I got 'undefined' when I tried to get the data from client request via req.body or req.params in server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to `axios.post` needs to have a `data` key. eg `{ data: post }`

Comment: the key name has to be data? can I call it others?